# Best approach to eliminate oversegmentation in Watershed algorithm to enhance edges?

Tags: java, algorithm, image-segmentation, threshold, watershed

I am trying to implement the Watershed algorithm for image segmentation. I applied in the pre-processing phase Median filter and Morphological Gradient, but the results are way too over segmented as seen in the pictures above. After some research on web I found that adaptive thresholding might be a solution. Otsu's method is not desirable for me, since I am trying to enhance the edges as well as possible, for a further extraction of the objects from the background.

Original elephant image:

[image]

Oversegmented image:

[image]

Thank you and hopefully you can give me an advice on how to make it work on Java since most of the solutions are in matlab!

Comment: Try to use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator for the pre-processing. It is an approximation of the gradient and already contains smoothing.

Comment: Thank you! Still, my Morphological Gradient filter does a pretty good job at enhancing the edges, but what I would need would be a binarized version of any such filter. Applying different global threshold values, I obtained fair results for not so complex images, but a global value is clearly not the best option. Furthermore, the thresholding should be done automatically..